# Get Changesets Associated With Build

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

In TFS (2013 Update 4) I am trying to write a PowerShell script to copy modified SQL files that are tied to a build.  I can get and copy the appropriate files if I know the changeset number, which will often be enough (I can use the TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION environment variable when the build is triggered by a merge).  However, occasionally there will be a handful of changesets that are associated with the build in TFS.

Using the Build Number, how do I get a list of Changesets?

Comment: Is this for release purposes? If so, you'll be much better served by using SSDT and publishing your database schema during your release process.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, it is to be run as a Post-Build script.  Perhaps we would be better off, but process (and the DBA) dictates that we must handle SQL deployments (model changes, data updates, proc changes, etc.) via a manually created (by the DBA) set of deployment scripts.  The DBA uses the files we provide in a network folder to create the scripts.  Right now, the team lead must manually gather the list and them manually copy the files.  I am looking only to eliminate our manual process, because it will be much easier than changing the way the DBA does things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your build number to find the previous build number. You will then have both a start changeset (from previous build) to current changeset (current build).

You can then walk the gap with the API and find all the intervening changesets.

Answer (score 0):

So I've done this in my last engagement, in essence we solved it by doing a get of all SQL related files EVERY build and produce a csv file that contained information about each file, name, version, and most importantly and MD5 hash of the file.  Then with each deployment we create/update/insert into a special deployment table in our DB all SQL "run" against that DB.  Then our build script is really just producing the csv file but our deployment script has the intelligence and checks to see if anything as changed in the csv file vs. the target DB and only applies changes (new SQL, changed SQL with new MD5).  So we essentially use two scripts.  I can't share the scripts but you have the idea.  Also I would look at this article by Alexander
[Automating SQL Server Database Deployments: Scripting Details](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automating-sql-server-database-deployments-scripting-details/) where he explains a lot about db migration.